# TCPDF output without saving file

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

How to use TCPDF to output pdf file in browser without saving like in ezpdf?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use `I` for "inline" to send the PDF to the browser, opposed to `F` to save it as a file.

`$pdf->Output('name.pdf', 'I');`

Comment: how do i send the output pdf as email attachment?

Comment: User $pdf->Output('name.pdf', 'E')

as per tcpdf documentation in "http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1"

E: return the document as base64 mime multi-part email attachment (RFC 2045)

Answer (score 60):

This is what I found out in the **documentation**.

> - **I** : send the file inline to the browser (default). The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
> - **D** : send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
> - **F** : save to a local server file with the name given by name.
> - **S** : return the document as a string (name is ignored).
> - **FI** : equivalent to F + I option
> - **FD** : equivalent to F + D option
> - **E** : return the document as base64 mime multi-part email attachment (RFC 2045)

Comment: I was looking for F to save pdf file on server. Thanks

Comment: Strange, using PHPMailer to send the PDF as an attachment, the file is corrupted if I use "E", but produces a functional PDF if I use "S", but with "S" none of the images are visible in the PDF.

Comment: I have a similar issue.... I implemented : `$pdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/mytestfile.pdf', 'FD');`
as like as `$pdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/mytestfile.pdf', 'D');` but browser's doesn't open download window to get the PDF... could maybe be related to some php download settings ? if yes, which option I should look at ?

Answer (score 13):

If You want to open dialogue window in browser to save, not open with PDF browser viewer (I was looking for this solution for a while), You should use 'D':

```
$pdf->Output('name.pdf', 'D');
```

Answer (score 3):

Print the PDF header (using header() function) like:
`header("Content-type: application/pdf");`

and then just echo the content of the PDF file you created (instead of writing it to disk).

Answer (score 3):

Hint - with a saving file:

```
$pdf->Output('sandbox/pdf/example.pdf', 'F');
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the `Output("doc.pdf", "I");` and it doesn't work, I'm always asked for saving the file.

I took a look in documentation and found that

I send the file inline to the browser (default). The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1

Then I think you have to use a plugin to print it, otherwise it is going to be downloaded.

Comment: The "plug-in" referred to in the documentation you're quoting is the browser plugin.  If your browser doesn't have a PDF viewer plugin (or built-in support), you'll probably be prompted to download it - but that depends on the behaviour of the browser in question.

Answer (score 1):

It works with `I` for inline as stated, but also with `O`.

```
$pdf->Output('name.pdf', 'O');
```

It is perhaps easier to remember (`O` for Open).

Comment: Got error:  `TCPDF ERROR: Incorrect output destination: O`

Answer (score -2):

```
      $filename= time()."pdf"; 
    //$filelocation = "C://xampp/htdocs/Nilesh/Projects/mkGroup/admin/PDF";

     $filelocation = "/pdf uplaod path/";
     $fileNL = $filelocation."/".$filename;

       $pdf->Output($fileNL,'F');
       $pdf->Output($filename, 'S');
```